# Deleting rows given a conditional vector - R

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, slice

Given this df:

```
   A B  C
1  a 1 53
2  a 0 27
3  a 1 46
4  b 1 42
5  c 0 97
6  d 1 46
7  d 0 24
```

And the values defined to match for deleting are in a vector:

```
values_delete <- c("b", "c")
```

How can I delete the rows in `df` using a conditional with the vector? I tried:

```
df2 <- df[df$A != values_delete,]
```

But it doesn't allow it. This is the error:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: `df[!df$A %in% values_delete, ]` ?

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) for `%in%`

```
df2 <- df[!(df$A %in% values_delete), ]
```